# Filter all group if one element satisfy a condition in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
df1 <- data.frame( id = c(1,1,2) , a = c('a','b','c'))
> df1
  id a
1  1 a
2  1 b
3  2 c
```

I would like to filter (remove) all element of a group defined on a variable if at least one element of the group satisfy a given condition.
Here, suppress lines corresponding to an id if variable a equals 'a'.

I tried the following, which removes only the line with a == 'a' as I wish the group with id == 1 would be filtered

```
> df1 %>%
+   group_by( id ) %>%
+   filter(  a != 'a')
# A tibble: 2 × 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id a    
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 b    
2     2 c
```

Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps use `all`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
 group_by(id) %>% 
 filter(all(a != 'a')) %>%
 ungroup
```

Or with `any`

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!any(a == 'a')) %>%
  ungroup
```

Or may use `%in%` as well

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!'a' %in% a) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Should be without the `!` in `all` to remove the `id 1` right?

Comment: Thank you.
The first does not work.
The second works well and it works also with %in%.
However, even if the third works I do not understand it. Why does a (variable) and 'a' value  interverts ?

Comment: @marc `'a' %in% a` returns a single TRUE/FALSE for each group, `!` negates that